# Update to 20.10 failed silently, now can't update due to package version mismatch with libc-bin and libc6:i386 / libc6:amd64

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.10, glibc

I am on Pop OS, which hews very closely to Ubuntu. A few days ago I tried to update my workstation from Pop OS 20.04 to 2010 by following the instructions on [System 76's website](https://support.system76.com/articles/upgrade-pop/) by running

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Then going to OS Upgrade, downloading 20.10, and rebooting. The version didn't change from 20.04. I was busy so I left it be for a bit.

I tried to update my software through the Pop Shop and got this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  locales: Depends: libc-bin (> 2.32)
```

I got a similar error when re-running `full-upgrade`, which also prompted me to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` which gave me another error:

```
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 package libc6:amd64 cannot be configured because libc6:i386 is not ready (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Some googling led me to try to reinstall the half-installed package with `sudo apt install --reinstall libc6-i386` which gave me a similar error:

```
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.32)
```

When attempting to install that specific version of `libc-bin` I got another error `E: Version '2.32' for 'libc-bin' was not found`

I checked the currently installed versions of libc6 and i seem to have 2.31-ubuntu9.2, not sure what that means exactly.

```
❯ dpkg -l | grep libc6  
rF  libc6:amd64                                      2.31-0ubuntu9.2                                           amd64        GNU C Library: Shared libraries
iHR libc6:i386                                       2.31-0ubuntu9.2                                           i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-dev:amd64                                  2.31-0ubuntu9.2                                           amd64        GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
ii  libc6-i386                                       2.31-0ubuntu9.2                                           amd64        GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64
```

I really don't want to start from scratch with this machine, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to manually force dpkg to complete the installation of libc6:i386, at which point apt should be able to "think" its way through the dist-upgrade process again. It should just be a matter of invoking:

```bsh
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_i386.deb`
```

The filename might not be exactly as I've shown it here, though, so you should verify it first with:

```bsh
ls /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6*
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you Peter!